# how to stop page jumping and maintain both panel & browser scroll position when user click on datalist item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, maintainscrollpositionon

I have a datalist inside the panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"  ScrollBars="Vertical">
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" CaptionAlign="Left">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="btn1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Images.ashx?Name=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path") %>'
           OnCommand="Item_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() +";"+Eval("Path")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
```

On Item_Command I am adding the style to btn1 such as border and color, and getting the id of selected item

```
string[] str = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
Id = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
```

When I am selecting the item page is jumping, suppose I have scrolled browser scrollbar to bottom and selected an image browser scroll is going on top and again its coming on bottom, On Item_Command I am enabling and disabling few other btn which is out side of datalist, if i am keeping the datalist inside the updatepanel then all other btn is not getting enable or disable thats why i am not using update panel. I have all the controls  inside the update panel. I tried with [how to retain the browser scroll position after any event gets fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109505/how-to-retain-the-browser-scroll-position-after-any-event-gets-fire) but its not working, i am setting

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
AutoEventWireup="true"
```

that also not working for me. I am using VS 2010, 4.0 with C#.

Some one plz tell me how to stop page jumping and maintain both panel1 and browser scroll position when user click on datalist item?

thanks in advanced..

Comment: Have you tried nesting your `DataList` inside an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: yes, but I can't keep my datalist inside the update panel, if i'll keep it inside the update panel someother functionality is going to disturb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a clientside function on Client click event of your image button like this

> javascript:void(0);

, it works for me in update panel,

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="javascript:void(0);" ID="btn1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Help2.png" AlternateText="asas"/>
```

**Edit**

1. Put the button & datalist inside a updatePanel. Set

> UpdateMode=Conditional

for the udpatePanel.

1. When you perform your operation on the dataList row. Just update the update panel manually like this

> // Your image button event
>
> `YourUpdatePanel.Update();`

This coupled with what I posted earlier should fix your problem. Also you might not need MainScrollPositionOnPostBack=true by using above.

Damien.

Comment: I have a button as button1 which is out side of datalist, and on Item_Command I am enabling that when user is selecting the item, when I am using updatepanel then that button is not getting enable

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="datalistupdate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate> /* DataList*/ </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Are you performing a postback() ?

Comment: I tried with ur code but on Selecting the item button1 is not getting enabled which i have outside of datalist

Comment: its my btn <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this item?');" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's the thought: use either one big update panel, that covers the whole page to maintain page scrolling OR use multiple update panels to cover all items you want to have updated!

Comment: I already have one big Update Panel for the whole page but its not working for me, actually its a ascx page which is calling on a aspx page.

Comment: And having Updatepanels on the .aspx page is not an option for you? when rendered they all get updated...

Comment: no I can't use, I have a aspx in that i have a ascx and this ascx i have other ascx in which i am using uplodifyupload

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` true within Page tag:

```
 <%@ Page (...) MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" (...) %>
```